# Place form contents into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to integrate the 'uploadify' upload progress bar code into one of my sites. Normally all my fields are inside the form tags, and on submit they post and get processed.

Here, in order for the form contents to post, they have to be inside of the script. This works if there are fixed variables, but if I want other form contents - user inputs - included, they dont post, because the form tag in this set up is missing the 'action' section. Form variables are handled in the script.

I have tried to reference the (in this example) 'test' input inside the script, but it is not being read. I am trying to figure out how to read the form contents on submission into the script below the form.

```
 <form>
 <div id="queue"></div>
 <input id="test" name="test" type="text">
 <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 <?php $timestamp = time();?>
 $(function() {
 $('#file_upload').uploadify({
 'formData' : {
 'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
 'token' : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
 'test' : ???

 },
 'swf' : 'uploadify.swf',
 'uploader' : 'ul_beta.php'
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: `$("#test").val()` ?

Comment: I tried 'test' : '$("#test").val()' and 'test' : $("#test").val() but it did not post

Comment: This happens because `val()` is called when DOM is loaded, so you should call it from their event, before uploading. Check out my answer.